# What is the best way to search for a large number of words in a large number of files?

Tags: python, regex, search, file-search

I have around 5000 files and I need to find words in each of them from a list of 10000 words. My current code uses a (very) long regex to do it, but it's very slow.

```
wordlist = [...list of around 10000 english words...]
filelist = [...list of around 5000 filenames...]
wordlistre = re.compile('|'.join(wordlist), re.IGNORECASE)
discovered = []

for x in filelist:
    with open(x, 'r') as f:
        found = wordlistre.findall(f.read())
    if found:
        discovered = [x, found]
```

This checks files at a rate of around 5 files per second, which is a lot faster than doing it manually, however it's still very slow. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Consider using bash commands instead of Python if you're using Linux.

Comment: Use `threads` or `multiprocessing`

Comment: @Raptor I'm using windows, but it sounds feasible to copy the files over to a linux box.

Comment: get more computers...the speed of code doubles for every doubling of similar hardware :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `grep` on a command line, you can try the following:

```
grep -i -f wordlist.txt -r DIRECTORY_OF_FILES
```

You'll need to create a file `wordlist.txt` of all the words (one word per line).

Any lines in any of your files that match any of your words will be printed to STDOUT in the following format:

```
<path/to/file>:<matching line>
```

Comment: p.s. `grep` is unix-based only. Use `findstr` in Windows-based system: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732459.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Without more info on your data, a couple of thoughts are to use dictionaries instead of lists, and to reduce the data needed for searching/sorting.  Also consider using re.split if your delimiters are not as clean as below:

```
wordlist = 'this|is|it|what|is|it'.split('|')
d_wordlist = {}

for word in wordlist:
    first_letter = word[0]
    d_wordlist.setdefault(first_letter,set()).add(word)

filelist = [...list of around 5000 filenames...]
discovered = {}

for x in filelist:
    with open(x, 'r') as f:
        for word in f.read():
            first_letter = word[0]
            if word in d_wordlist[first_letter]:
                discovered.get(x,set()).add(word)

return discovered
```

Comment: Better to make a set out of wordlist and let python do the search optimisation. Btw. [file.read()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) does not return a list of words.

Answer (score 0):

The [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) was devised for precisely this usage, and implemented as `fgrep` in Unix.  With POSIX, the command `grep -F` is defined to perform this function.

It differs from regular `grep` in that it only uses fixed strings (not regular expressions) and is optimized for searching for a large number of strings.

To run it on a large number of files, specify the precise files on the command line, or pass them through `xargs`:

```
xargs -a filelist.txt grep -F -f wordlist.txt
```

The function of `xargs` is to fill up the command line with as many files as possible, and run `grep` as many times as necessary;

```
grep -F -f wordlist.txt (files 1 through 2,500 maybe)
grep -F -f wordlist.txt (files 2,501 through 5,000)
```

The precise number of files per invocation depends on the length of the individual file names, and the size of the `ARG_MAX` constant on your system.

Comment: It's not hard to find `grep` ports for Windows; but they may differ in quality.  I would suggest looking for GNU `grep` for Windows. The first Google hit for me is http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm

Comment: There are Python modules which implement this algorithm too, but I wouldn't know which one to recommend. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ahocorasick/0.9 is the top Google hit for me but it has a lower version number and looks less polished than https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyahocorasick/1.0.0